# Import a custom module created in one docker from another docker

Tags: python, docker, module

I have several python functionalities in my docker and I want others to use it from another docker image. How can I allow them to use my module without sharing my module files

Comment: set it up so they can use the network to make use of the functionality (web or sockets).  then either with internal docker network or host port call the functionality.  If you want a way to do it with the files I can not think of one.

Answer (score 0):

A Docker image contains a complete prepackaged *application*, or else it's a base that other images can build `FROM`.  Since each container has its own isolated filesystem, though, there's not any way to merge images, copy just a library (and all of its support files) from one image to another, or import a library that only exists in one image and use it in another.

In short: Docker isn't the right packaging mechanism here.  You should use Python's native packaging tools to distribute your library (the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) is probably a good starting point).  Once you've done that, you can include the library in `setup.py`/`setup.cfg`/`Pipfile`/`poetry.toml`/`requirements.txt` file, the same as any other library.

And then once you have the library packaged as a normal library, and included via one of the normal Python dependency systems, then when your Dockerfile `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` your library will be included too.

> ...without sharing my module files

This is impossible in Python.  A library always includes its source.  Docker doesn't particularly improve things, since an operator can fairly easily inspect or extract the contents of an image, including the plain-text Python source.  Choose a compiled language instead if this is a requirement.